# avoid vector copy constructor

Tags: c++, stl

I have a bunch of methods that return `vector<int>`. They don't return a reference or a pointer to `vector<int>` because the returned value is not a part of class' state, it is just generated on the fly depending on the method arguments.

I would like to avoid `vector<int>` copy constructor being called when I invoke the method like this.

```
vector<int> result = myClass.GenerateVectorOfInt(/* params */); 

// Do something with the result;
```

What is the best way to do it?

Would this be an acceptable way of doing that? Or are there any other better or more elegant solutions.

```
vector<int> result = std::move(myClass.GenerateVectorOfInt(/* params */));
```

Comment: Have you [verified](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fe331ecaf9498e7) that the copy constructor is actually being called?

Comment: Not before I posted the question. I've put a breakpoint in vector's copy constructor and it is not being hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need not do anything special, the compiler is allowed to elide the copy where feasible. This is called *"Return-Value Optimization"* (RVO).

If RVO does not occur, C++11 forces the `vector` to be moved into place, which is cheap, independent of its size. Usually this is 1 pointer and 2 integer assignments. So the vector will *never* be copied, the move is the worst case.

---

If for any reason RVO does not happen *and* a move is too expensive for your usecase (highly unlikely), there is nothing you can do without changing the function's signature; adding `std::move` or something like this at call point will not help.